# how to "include" another file as part of a Jenkins Pipeline definition

Tags: include, jenkins-pipeline

We have a large project that has multiple separate declarative pipeline file definitions.  This is used to build different apps and installers from the single code base.

Right now, all of these files contain a large block of "code" used to generate the email body and JIRA update messages.  examples:

```
// Get a JIRA's to add Comments to
// Return map of JIRA id to comment text from all commits for that JIRA
@NonCPS
def getJiraMap() {
  a bunch of stuff
return jiraset
}

// Get the body text for the emails
def getMailBody1() {
    return "See: ${BUILD_URL}\n\nChanges:\n" + getChangeString() + "\n" + testStatuses()
}

etc...
```

What I would like to do is have all these common methods in a separate file that all the other pipeline files can include.  This seems like it SHOULD be easy, but all examples I've found appear to be rather complex involving a separate SCM - which is NOT what I want.

Updates:

Going through the various suggestions given in that link, I make the following file - BuildTools.groovy:  Note that this file is in the same directory as the jenkins pipeline file that uses it.

```
import hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction
import hudson.model.Actionable

Class BuildTools {

// Get a JIRA's to add Comments to
// Return map of JIRA id to comment text from all commits for that JIRA
@NonCPS
def getJiraMap() {
    def jiraset = [:]
.. whole bunch of stuff ..
```

Here are the various things I've tried, and the results.

```
File sourceFile = new File("./AutomatedBuild/BuildTools.groovy");
Class gcl = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()).parseClass(sourceFile);
GroovyObject bt = (GroovyObject) gcl.newInstance();

Fails with:
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method java.lang.Class getClassLoader
```

```
evaluate(new File("./AutomatedBuild/BuildTools.groovy"))
def bt = new BuildTools()

Fails with:
    15:29:07  WorkflowScript: 8: unable to resolve class BuildTools 
    15:29:07   @ line 8, column 10.
    15:29:07     def bt = new BuildTools()
    15:29:07              ^
```

```
import BuildTools
def bt = new BuildTools()

Fails with:
    15:35:58  WorkflowScript: 16: unable to resolve class BuildTools (note that BuildTools.groovy is in the same folder as this script)
    15:35:58   @ line 16, column 1.
    15:35:58     import BuildTools
    15:35:58     ^
```

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
def bt = shell.parse(new File("./AutomatedBuild/BuildTools.groovy"))

Fails with:
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new groovy.lang.GroovyShell
```

Answer (score 0):

Shared libraries designed for your.

Also You may add class or function from groovy file with **load** step to load yours classes functions and stages:

```java
my_module = load 'path/to/file/in/repo.groovy'
my_module.myCoolClass()
```